# how to solve MvxIoCResolveException

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

```
 protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        RegisterForDetailsRequests(bundle);
    }
    {
        RegisterFragment<HomeFragment,HomeFragmentViewModel>(typeof(HomeFragmentViewModel).Name, bundle, new HomeFragmentViewModel());

    }
    public void RegisterFragment<TFragment, TViewModel>(string tag, Bundle args, IMvxViewModel viewModel = null)
        where TFragment : IMvxFragmentView
        where TViewModel : IMvxViewModel
    {
        var customPresenter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFragmentsPresenter>();
        customPresenter.RegisterViewModelAtHost<TViewModel>(this);

    }
```

This is my code and I am getting this error:

> Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: Cirrious.CrossCore.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve type Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging.Presenter.IMvxFragmentsPresenter

Comment: Did you register the custom presenter in _Setup_? See https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Setup.cs#L41 for an example.